# How to specify schema and other arguments

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to write a class in SqlAlchemy. I want to specify unique constraint on 3 columns as well as pass schema in `__table_args__`.

```
class State(Base):
    __tablename__ = "state"
    __table_args__ = {'schema': 'demo'}

  # Of course This will Fail. I am overriding value of '__table_args__' :)

   __table_args__ = (
    Index('st_id', id, state, unique=True)
   )

    id = Column(String(ID_LEN), primary_key=True)
    state = Column(String(50))
```

Can somebody help me doing this?

Answer (score 0):

In order to define columns with UNIQUE constraints, see this [link](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/constraints.html#unique-constraint). As for specifying the schema within **table_args**, what you have looks correct.